# How to set an attribute from a parent view to always be the same?

Tags: android, attributes, android-custom-view

Let's say I have a class `MyView` that extends `TextView`. For the sake of the argument, let's also say that `MyView` must always have `TextView`'s attribute `clickable` to be true. Is there a way to set it to true in `MyView` so that `clickable` is not settable the the XML layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In your constructor, after you call super, call super.setClickable(true).  That will overwrite whatever the xml set.  Then override setClickable so that it either does nothing or throws an exception, so they can't change it programatically.